# kentico smart search filter

Tags: visual-studio, kentico, aspx-user-control

I want to implement a smart search filter in my project,  I already bulit a smart search box connected to a searchResults page, but now I want to add more options to filter these results. I am not using a web part structure so I have to implement this functionality in visual studio as a controller in aspx page. I could'nt find any example on how to do this. Can you please explain the process? or at least provide me with links where I can find examples?

also please note that I m not able to add it as a webpart directly from Kentico, I want to implement it in visual studio programatically

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [smart search syntax](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/smart-search-syntax).  You’ll need to use this to combine with or replace your search term once you set the filter value in your user control.

Comment: hello, I m sorry but the link you shared was'nt helpful, I couldnt find how I should be building my filter in visual studio as an ASPX control. Please I really need an example (or more than one if available) so I can understand the process that I should follow to build my filter.

Comment: The links contain the formatting that you would need to use, but I guess you're not at that point.  Is there any reason that you cannot use the controls in your Kentico solution: `CMS\Webparts\SmartSearch\SearchFilter.ascx` and  `CMS\Webparts\SmartSearch\SearchBox.ascx`.  I've not done this since Kentico 7 when I last did an ASPX template, but as I recall you can put these controls on an ASPX page.